# Is there any NOP operation in RxJava?

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming

Is there any NOP (no operation) operation for observables?

Would like to turn `BehaviorSubject` to read-only observable with it, like this:

```
private BehaviourSubject<String> statusSubject = new BehaviorSubject<String>("Ready");
public Observable<String> statusObservable() {
    return 
       statusSubject
       .nop();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For RxJava 1.0 there is [`Observable.asObservable()`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#asObservable())

For RxJava 2.0 there is [`Observable.hide()`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#hide())

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to get only the Observable aspect of Subject, without the 'writer' capabilities of subject, which can be retrieved using [Subject.asObservable()](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#asObservable()) method.